# Is it safe to convert this partition table from GPT to MBR?

Tags: linux, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I think I need to convert my partition table from GPT to MBR in order to fix a problem with the bootloader.

Here is the output of `gdisk -l /dev/sdb`

> ```
> GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8
>
> Partition table scan:
>   MBR: protective
>   BSD: not present
>   APM: not present
>   GPT: present
>
> Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
> Disk /dev/sdb: 976773168 sectors, 465.8 GiB
> Logical sector size: 512 bytes
> Disk identifier (GUID): 628AC5FC-691C-7F42-B600-FDA3A3B87EEE
> Partition table holds up to 128 entries
> First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 976773134
> Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
> Total free space is 10221 sectors (5.0 MiB)
>
> Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
>    1           10240       195311615   93.1 GiB    0700  
>    2       195311616       976773119   372.6 GiB   0700
> ```

I don't really understand the difference between GPT and MBR types, what "protective" means here, or what issues might arise.

I am looking at [these instructions](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html#gpt2mbr). They describe quite a few caveats. Do they apply to my disk? How do I find out? How can I recover if this goes wrong?

Comment: Now you're just rewording [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/883877/will-converting-my-partition-table-from-gpt-to-mbr-fix-my-failed-bootloader-inst).  Please rather edit and update [your original question](http://superuser.com/questions/843921/whats-wrong-with-this-grub-setup), and perhaps put a bounty on it to draw attention. Always asking about [XY problems](http://xyproblem.info/) is not very effective. (I'm also willing to give your question a bounty worth 50 if you update your original post.)

Comment: It's not the same question! By analogy the initial question is "why am I sick?" and the final question is "will this particular medication kill me?" I understand that you're trying to de-clutter the site, but it seems to me entirely reasonable to keep them apart.

Comment: In that analogy, we'd rather have people tell you that directly in an answer to the original question. I also understand that you're trying out different options, digging further, but this is something better suited for a discussion forum or [chat], not spread across multiple questions where it's easy enough to miss the whole picture. It's not only *my* intention to de-clutter, but other users and moderators handled previous questions similarly. Honestly, I'd recommend you to just rephrase your first question and add a little context explaining what you've tried and what you'd like to know.